# Laravel get data where relation doesn't contain specific data

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have Invoice Model Along with Invoice Log.

Invoice Log Contains following data

```
id-----invoice_id----status--
1------16------------processing
2------16------------shipped
3------16------------delivered
4------16------------returned
5------17------------processing
6------17------------shipped
7------18------------processing
```

I want invoice object where the invoice log of that invoice doesn't contain 'delivered' or 'returned' status.

I want invoice id 17 and 18 as result.

I have tried

```
$invoices = Invoice::whereHas('logs', function ($query) {
    $query->where('invoice_status','!=', 'delivered')->where('invoice_status','!=', 'returned');
})->get();
```

But that return wrong value.

Comment: Is your column name `status` but you are querying by `invoice_status` ?Just saying by your table definition and query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your solution is really close - could you try the following with a `whereDoesntHave`?

```
$invoices = Invoice::whereDoesntHave('logs', function ($query) {
    $query->where('invoice_status','!=', 'delivered')
          ->orWhere('invoice_status','!=', 'returned');
})->get();
```

Comment: yes. But not worked. because there still remains shipping and processing status of same invoice_id